# Graphical layout and emulator scope

Tags: android

My graphical layout view and the running emulator view is different. I made a landscape layout which shows different in running emulator than the graphical layout's view.What can I do to match them (at least 95%). Take a look at the button position in my  Graphical layout view and the view in emulator. How can it be so different. The white background is supposed to be the boundary of my device in Graphical layout.[image]

This is what I get in running emulator in landscape mode, see the button is gone- 
[image]

and this is my emulator settings-

[image]

This is my xml code for landscape layout-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="0dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:paddingRight="80dp"
                android:text="Age"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="0dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Height"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="0dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Weight"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="0dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Sex"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:entries="@array/sex" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="0dp" >

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio0"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="Metric" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Imperial" />
            </RadioGroup>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingTop="0dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="OK" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="BMR Calculator"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your emulator and graphical Layout does not shows you in the same manner.There is always quite difference between these two things.So you should always check it with real device. You can force your activity to be visible either in landscape or portrate mode by using following command.

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>
```

Try to use `ScrollView` for your layout so that your button will be visible in landscape mode.

Comment: but if I force it will always show up in landscape mode, isnt it? which I dont actually.

Comment: can u exactly say the difference between emulator and graphical Layout and what to do to make it right, thanx

Comment: @Tanvir There is little bit difference between your graphical layout and emulator/device presentation.There is not any fixed difference.

Comment: Why dont these two match ? and if I can so ?

Comment: Read this post to support multiple screen 'http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html'

Comment: I read it but there's nothing related to what I want. I think the graphical layout presentation can be changed by making a custom device configuration which resembles my real device. But to do this I have another problem. it asks for x dpi, y dpi , screen width/height, ratios etc. how can I find each for my device ? This is what I get from my real device configuration- 240 x 320 pixels, 2.8 inches (~143 ppi pixel density)